# Python: Combining two functions

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am not typically a Python user. Could someone help me with combining the two functions below into one?

```
def Reverse(Pattern):
    rev = []
    n = len(Pattern)
    for i in range(n):
        n = n-1
    rev.append(Pattern[::-1])
    return rev[0]

def Complement(Pattern):
  complements = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "G":"C", "C":"G"}
  nucleotides = []
  for i in Pattern:
      nucleotides += complements[i]
  return "".join(nucleotides)
```

I want it to be consolidated into this:

```
def ReverseComplement(Pattern):   
    rev = []
    n = len(Pattern)
    for i in range(n):
        n = n-1
    rev.append(Pattern[::-1])
    return rev[0] ##I've tried getting rid of this but it's not working properly
    complements = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "G":"C", "C":"G"}
    nucleotides = []
    for i in rev:
        nucleotides += rev[i]
    return "".join(nucleotides)
```

As a test, "ACACAC" should return "GTGTGT".

Comment: Am I missing something--what does the first for loop in function `Reverse` do?  Aren't you just returning Pattern[::-1]?  Why all the other code?

Comment: You are returning two statement without any if condition. So it will always `return` the first return statement i.e: `return rev[0]`

Comment: Thanks @Angela C for accepting my answer. Kindly vote up my answer to. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def ReverseComplement(Pattern):
    complements = {"A":"G", "G":"A", "T":"C", "C":"T"}
    nucleotides = []
    for i in Pattern:
        nucleotides += complements[i]
    return "".join(nucleotides)

print(ReverseComplement("ACACAC"))
```

Comment: Now your function does not reverse. For instance, if you try it on "AACGGT", the reverse-complement should be "ACCGTT", but your function gives "GGTAAC".

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you want to combine two functions you've already written, you can simply compose them by calling one with the return value of the other:

```
def reverse_complement(pattern):
    return Reverse(Complement(pattern))
```

It's almost always preferable to simply reuse code you've already written rather than copy+paste it.  Having multiple versions of code just increases the surface area for bugs to appear and increases the work involved in maintaining the code; if you write one version of a function, you only have to write one set of tests, and you only have to fix bugs in one place.

In this particular case, though, a lot of the code you've written can be discarded or simplified.  The `Reverse` function is already built directly into Python (with the name `reversed`), and the `Complement` function can be shortened into a single `map` call into your dict.  All together it's simply:

```
def reverse_complement(pattern: str) -> str:
    complements = {"A": "T", "T": "A", "G": "C", "C": "G"}
    return "".join(map(complements.get, reversed(pattern)))
```

Comment: I understand this is the easiest way but I am looking to create an entirely new function and get rid of the other two.

Comment: You could just take the other two and define them as inner functions if you don't want to expose them as separate public functions...

Comment: Okay, after reviewing the details of those functions, yeah, it's easier to just implement the whole thing in two lines.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) function could be be a solution that doesn't require lists.

```
def rev_comp(pattern):
    return pattern.translate(str.maketrans('ATGC', 'TACG'))[::-1]

pat = "ACACAC"

print(rev_comp(pat))
```

Prints:

```
GTGTGT
```